# AWS Database Migration Service requires a role not mentioned in documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services, database, migration, oracle

I am trying to perform a database migration using AWS Database Migration Service (DMS) from a self-managed database on EC2 to AWS RDS. I get this message when I try to run the task to perform the migration.

```
dms-access-for-tasks IAM Role not configured correctly
```

The AWS DMS documentation is silent when it comes to a role called `dms-access-for-tasks`. What policy does it need associating to? Please help.

Comment: Hi, if the response below answered your question please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault way of saying *Thanks* for the time someone took to help you :)

Answer (score 3):

There seem to be quite a good list of roles and policies needed for DMS at **[IAM Permissions Needed to Use AWS DMS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Security.IAMPermissions.html)** and **[IAM Roles to Use With the AWS DMS API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Security.APIRole.html)** - have you got all of that configured correctly? If you still can't make it work post the DMS IAM Role details.

Comment: Links are broken.  They just go to a generic DMS page with no mention of IAM.

Answer (score 2):

The IAM permissions required to use DMS are explained in the AWS documentation pages https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Security.html#CHAP_Security.IAMPermissions and https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Security.html#CHAP_Security.APIRole

Comment: This is the updated documentation. Thanks!